# Visual Studio Release code is slower than Debug code when usaing printf to a Windows console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, release, iostream

I'm working on a project to draw shapes to CMD using `printf` but I found a weird behavior. When I compile the code using Debug mode the running program is slower but the output to the console is faster (60 FPS). When I compile it as a Release code the running program is around 10x faster but the output image lags. (around 4 FPS)

**Is there anything wrong with `iostream` library when compiling as a Release?**
In both situations my statistics (in a video linked dow bellow) are showing 60 FPS but the look of the Release code feels like 4 FPS.

I have only video with the Debug code. In the **Debug code** my main loop is around **200 000 ticks a second** and it **feels like 60 FPS** and the **Release code** is **over 1 000 000 ticks per second** but the `printf` seems **like 4 FPS**.

I made a frame cap to limit it to 60 FPS to avoid any problems.

It is also weird that it lags in Windows 10 CMD but not in Windows 11 CMD. (I'm compiling it using Windows 10 preset on Windows 10 machine using Visual Studio 2017)

It is really frustrating because the only way to achieve smooth experience is to run the program always in Debug mode. (or to run the Release version on a Windows 11 machine)

**Is Release code using a different version of Wnidows CMD than Debug code? And are there any settings for a Release code in Visual Studio to fix it?**

This is the smooth result when doing Debug output instead of Release.
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4a5XXLaCZo)

Thanks.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is inherently slow. Try running this in `Terminal` (installed from the App Store), thats what Windows 11 uses by default AFAIK, thats why its running faster.

Comment: Note that `printf` is an old C function, it's not part of the C++ iostreams library. And why aren't you actually *using* the iostreams library, with `std::cout` instead of `printf`? It won't make a difference in your case, but at least you will avoid the risk of quite a few subtle bugs and chances for undefined behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well I'm using `printf` because I was searching for a speed difference and around 80% of people were saying that `printf` is faster. But if you think that this may be the problem then I can try to change that. I'm using `printf c_str()` to print the image.

Comment: Can you share a sample for testing?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I'm sorry. It looks like that the reason whas that a Release code actually runs much quicker an it was resulting in extremelly low numbers in my deltaTime variable in custom class Time. So it was pretty much dividing by zero all the time. float variable in dletaTime() which is 0.0000000000F is bad for using timers. I figured this problem after I was testing it.